# How can I check if the user's email is already existing in firebase authentication using PHP?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am a newbie in programming :>. I want to register a user's account in firebase authentication and at the same time store the details in a real-time database. In the given code, I can already add user details to both the real-time database and firebase authentication. I'll attach the code I did.

```
<?php
session_start();

  include('databaseconfig.php');
  //this is for add button
   if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    //constraint for password and confirm password (I'm not using firebase authentication in this one)
    if($password = $_POST['password'] == $cpassword = $_POST['confirmPassword']){

      $fName = $_POST['givenName'];
      $lName = $_POST['lastName'];
      $bDay = $_POST['birthDate'];
      $gradeLevel = $_POST['gradeLevel'];
      $school = $_POST['school'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      $question = $_POST['securityQuestion'];
      $answer = $_POST['answer'];

      $userProperties = [
        'email' => $email,
        'emailVerified' => false,
        'password' => $password,
    ];

    $createdUser = $auth->createUser($userProperties);


    if ($createdUser) {

      $postData = [
        'first_name' => $fName,
        'last_name' => $lName,
        'bithday' => $bDay,
        'grade_level' => $gradeLevel,
        'school' => $school,
        'email_address' => $email,
        'password' => $password,
        'security_question' => $question,
        'answer' => $answer
      ];

      $reference_table = "Profiles";
      $postRef = $database->getReference($reference_table)->push($postData);

      if($postRef){
          ?>
          <script>
          alert("User Added Successfully");
          </script>
          <?php
          header('Location:userlist.php');
      }
      else{
           ?>
          <script>
          alert("User not Added");
          </script>
          <?php
      }
      exit();
    } else {
          ?>
          <script>
          alert("Email already exists.");
          </script>
          <?php
    }  
  }
}

?>
```

However, if the user tried to register an email address that is already existing in the firebase authentication it will result to a fatal error. I don't know how to fix this. Please help me

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS", "errors": [ { "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS" (truncated...) in C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(69): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL, Array, NULL) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(204): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(153): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(48): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise{closure}() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(248): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run(true) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(224): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn() #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(269): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending() #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(226): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList() #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending() #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(187): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait() #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient.php(227): GuzzleHttp\Client->request('POST', 'signupNewUser', Array) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient.php(45): Kreait\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient->requestApi('signupNewUser', Array) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Auth.php(143): Kreait\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient->createUser(Object(Kreait\Firebase\Request\CreateUser)) #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\addUser.php(29): Kreait\Firebase\Auth->createUser(Array) #14 {main} Next Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Auth\EmailExists: The email address is already in use by another account. in C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Exception\AuthApiExceptionConverter.php:73 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Exception\AuthApiExceptionConverter.php(47): Kreait\Firebase\Exception\AuthApiExceptionConverter->convertGuzzleRequestException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient.php(229): Kreait\Firebase\Exception\AuthApiExceptionConverter->convertException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient.php(45): Kreait\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient->requestApi('signupNewUser', Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Auth.php(143): Kreait\Firebase\Auth\ApiClient->createUser(Object(Kreait\Firebase\Request\CreateUser)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\addUser.php(29): Kreait\Firebase\Auth->createUser(Array) #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\maintenanceadmin\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Exception\AuthApiExceptionConverter.php on line 73`

Comment: Not sure if PHP SDK has built in method but you should be able to use Firebase Auth REST API ([Fetch providers for emails](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-fetch-providers-for-email)) and check that.

Answer (score 1):

I can see from your stack trace that you are using [kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) (hello, I'm the maintainer ).

I'm glad you posted this question because it is already possible to check for duplicate emails, but it wasn't documented .

I made up for it with [this commit](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/commit/12a01145fb2587ece4ff25818068d5ae82f55a9e), and you can find the newly added section on the [User Management Page in the docs](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-management.html#duplicate-unregistered-email-addresses).

Now, based on the code you provided, the following change should work:

```php
<?php

// ...

try {
    $createdUser = $auth->createUser($userProperties);
} catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Auth\EmailExists $e) {
    $createdUser = null;
}

if ($createdUser) {
    // ...
} else { ?>
    <script>
        alert("Email already exists.");
    </script>
<?php
}

// ...
```

This wraps the `createUser()` operation in a [`try/catch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) block: if a given email already exists, the Firebase API response is converted to an `EmailExists` exception which you then can handle. To stay within your code, the `catch` block sets `$createdUser` to `null` so that the following condition (`if ($createdUser) {}`) works as you intended it.